# TypeScript re-export interface from a core library inside namespace

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'd like to declare a namespace `GraphQLScalars` that as of right now only should contain a single export, `Date` which should be of same type as the native `Date` interface found in the [`es5` lib](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/ee25cdecbca49b2b5a290ecd65224f425b1d6a9c/src/lib/es5.d.ts#L638-L790).

I have unsuccessfully attempted this with the following snippet:

```
declare namespace GraphQLScalars {
    export type Date = Date
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture the global type outside to prevent name collision inside. e.g.:

```
declare type __date = Date;
declare namespace GraphQLScalars {
    export type Date = __date;
}
```